How to I Create A Full Screen Paging Flatlist, When Theres Other Static Elements On Screen?
I'm trying to create a FlatList that will page, in a similiar style to the TikTok scroll feed, however, I have a header at the top of the page, and a navigation bar at the bottom.
My layout is like this

<SafeAreaView>
  <Text>Header</Text>
  <FlatList />
</SafeAreaView>

This is also accompanied by the react navigation bottom navigation bar. My problem is, I don't know what height to set the render item, so that each item takes the full screen, and it pages naturally like TikTok or Instagram.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
